# Canvas for a part of the layout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I have a layout which is divided into 2 layout , Layout-1 and Layout-2. How to use canvas only in Layout 1. Any pointer/example to this scenario will be a great help.

[image]

Comment: I guess you don't know what `Canvas` is... Or may be by `Canvas` you mean something else. Are you familiar with custom components?

Comment: nope. My requirement is to make a part of the screen as a drawable one. I know the onDraw and Canvas concept helps. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Now I have a feeling that you don't know about `drawable`. :-\

Comment: Come one I still don't know what you are asking? do you want custom component at layout-1 place ?

Comment: You could make use of fragments, and have a "canvas" object (BitmapView) occupy the left layout (layout 1)...

Comment: If you are talking about an HTML5 canvas object, then just have layout1 be a WebView, with a javascript bridge between the WebView and the Android code...

Comment: Yes I am new to Android. By layout I am splitting my screen into 2. One I am calling as Layout 1 and another as Layout 2. I need to make the Layout 1 as a place where the user can write something